# how to seed one to many relationship in laravel 7

Tags: php

I have this migrations and I want to see them using a factory model

migration category:

```
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id_cat');
        $table->string('nom');

    });
```

migration marque :

```
        Schema::create('marques', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('marque_id');
        $table->foreignId('cat_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('designation');
    });
```

when I run this factory model it doesnt work

category factory:

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'nom' => $faker->unique()->word
];
```

});

marque factory :

```
$factory->define(Marque::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'cat_id' => Category::all()->random()->id,
    'designation'=>$faker->unique()->word
];
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your model property fillable mass assignment array is fill.

example for `Category::class`:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
   /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['nom'];

}
```

You have to do the same for your other class mass assignment property. To get more information about read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).
Good luck and happy coding!